# MongoDB Morphia says deprecated use

Tags: java, mongodb, annotations, morphia

My application works fine. I used this official reference to learn morphia:

```
http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.2/getting-started/quick-tour/
```

In Employee class :

```
@Indexes(
    @Index(value = "salary", fields = @Field("salary"))
)
```

It says value is Deprecated use fields(). How can I write Index annotation to get rid of deprecated use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just drop the value attribute. The information is already given by fields attribute :

```
@Indexes(@Index(fields = @Field("salary")))
```

This should work

For further information, take a look at : https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/AllAnnotations